# Can callbacks in java be implemented without anonymous classes and lambda expressions?

Tags: java

Most of the research I have done keeps coming up with the same thing which is java implements callbacks using anonymous classes before java 1.8 or lambda expressions in java 1.8 and above.

It has been stated on the “Is a function callback in Java also an anonymous class?” question that callbacks() can be implemented 2 ways in java which makes sense to me. ( correct me if I am wrong )

From code example #1. below, YourMouseListener is defined so all we have to do is instantiate an object and pass that instance to a method, meaning callbacks() can be implemented without anonymous classes or lambda expressions.

In code example #2 solution is implemented with anonymous class which is fine, I just don’t see that it brings any functionality that can’t be done with example #1 methodology.

1. So, actually, the first way to implement this callback is you declare a class extends MouseAdapter

   ```
    public class YourMouseListener extends MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { ... } 
    } 

    // then create an instance and passes to it:
    c.addMouseListener(new YourMouseListener() );
   ```
2. To minimize code and class declaration, Java enable you to use anonymous classes to achieve callbacks() like:

   ```
    c.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Mouse entry event: " + e
                  + " on button: " + buttonLabel);  }});
   ```

So my question is, in Java, can callbacks be implemented without anonymous classes and lambda expressions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can certainly use [functional interfaces](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces) instead of anonymous inner classes, if you want to implements callbacks like the ones you'd use when using listeners

Comment: *"can callbacks be implemented without anonymous classes and lambda expressions"* - the example number 1 in your question is the answer to this question. If you give the class a name then it is not anonymous.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course! Callbacks, event listeners, etc. are just types. Java gives many ways to create implementations of interfaces, including anonymous classes and lambda expressions (for functional interfaces).

The option of providing implementations using normal classes is always open. Sometimes it's even preferred, as in cases where the code would be duplicated when the same kind of callback is passed for different events.

The drive for anonymous classes and lambda expressions is brevity and, of course, the fact that callbacks are usually fit-for-purpose code that you use for one event (such as a specific listener code for specific buttons - it's only in rare cases that one needs to reuse code for things like mouse click events).

In many cases, it's convenient to write just the code for it using a lambda expression (when a functional interface applicable) or an anonymous class, instead of writing a separate class for it.

Comment: If the option of providing implementations using normal classes is always open then would it be safe to say that every object passed into a method() is a callback()?

Comment: Don't get too hooked to the term "callback". There are countless patterns that introduce terms like that (callback, listener, handler, event, controller, observer, etc.). All these patterns end up being implemented using types in Java, and you get to instantiate those types one way or another. What you pass to the method that allows you to register a *callback* is an object of a certain type (a listener, etc.). Beyond that, it's plain old Java: you create an object of a class that implements that type/interface - and that could be a normal/anonymous class, maybe a lambda if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you can do with an anonymous class you can do with a named class. Just declare a named class that does the same thing. Anonymous classes were just a convenience to avoid having a bunch of class definitions that were used only once.

A callback would be expressed as an interface passed as an argument to a method. Whether the object implementing the callback is instantiated using a named class or an anonymous class makes no difference to the JVM.